# Cakephp 3 model paginate

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I have three tables

EventInvites
Contacts
Organisations

An invite has one contact and a contact has one Organisations

The data is displayed correctly using something like.

```
  $invitees = $this->CrmEventInvites->find()
            ->where(['CrmEventInvites.crm_event_id' => $CrmEvent->id, 'CrmEventInvites.deleted' => '0'])
            ->contain(['CrmContacts' => ['CrmOrganisations','CrmContactRoles.CrmRoles'] ]

                        );
```

My pagination is working fine for contact name invite status etc but I can't figure out to sort by crmcontacts -> organisations.name

```
$this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => ['CrmContacts.lastname','CrmContacts.job_title','CrmOrganisations.name','CrmEventInviteStatus.status','CrmEventInvites.price_paid'],
        'contain' => ['CrmContacts' => 'CrmOrganisations','CrmEventInviteStatus'],
        'order' => ['CrmContacts.lastname' => 'asc'],
    'url' => ['sort' => null, 'direction' => null]
    ];
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `'order' => ['CrmOrganisations.name' => 'asc']`?

Comment: Yeah that didnt work. thanks